# How to git ignore everything but one folder?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-add

I have a git repo in my home folder. I'm trying to NOT include basically the entirety of my home folder, with the exception of my .vim folder.

In my .gitignore, I have

`*
!.vim`

The problem is that this only adds the `.vim` directory into my git repo, but not its files and its subdirectories (and its files, and its subdirectories, and so on). I'd like to have `.vim` and ALL of its subfiles and subdirectories into my git repo. How do I change this `.gitignore` for the desired behavior?

Comment: Why not make your .vim folder the git repository?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude a folder *content*, you would need to exclude first folders (because of the [parent directory rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)):

```
*
!*/
```

Then you can exclude the `.vim/` folder content:

```
!.vim/**
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` includes the current directory, so you're being bitten by this:

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. ***It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.*** Git doesn't list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

I don't know of any way to say "*everything in the top level directory except the top level directory*".

If you only want to put `.vim` into Git, you should put your Git repository in `.vim`.